# phpmyadmin - new install leads to blank screen

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just installed a new VPS. Debian 8.0 x64.  I've installed iRedMail (http://www.iredmail.org/) and made the following config choices:

- Debian 8.0 x64
- Apache
- MariaDB

I installed phpmyadmin via git.  I set the server to require SSL.  When I attempt to reach it ( https://server/phpmyadmin/ ), I only see a blank page.

When I visit /var/log/apache2/error.log, I see:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function __() in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/core.lib.php on line 235
```

I've searched for this error message, and I've seen several suggestions.  This is what it is NOT:

- `session.save_path` is set to `3;/var/lib/php/sessions`. that directory is owned by `www-data`, and permissions are set to 777.
- I have reinstalled all php modules, and that did not fix the issue.
- per `dpkg -l`, these php modules are installed:

  - php-gettext
  - php-tcpdf
  - php5-cli
  - php5-common
  - php5-curl
  - php5-gd
  - php5-intl
  - php5-json
  - php5-mcrypt
  - php5-mysql
  - php5-readline
  - phpmyadmin

furthermore, when I navigate to `https://server/phpmyadmin/setup`, I'm given a popup challenge to enter a username and password.  I've tried root/[null], root/[root mysql password], admin/[root mysql password].  Nothing works.  I can log into mysql from the command prompt using `mysql -u root -p` and entering root password.

What am I missing?  Thank you!

Comment: I don't have an immediate answer for you, but this is an excellent question. You've clearly researched some common causes of this problem and answered a lot of the common introductory questions we usually have to ask.

Comment: Actually, I wonder about the "3" in your session.save_path -- the garbage collector doesn't run when setting the number of subdirectory levels like this; could you remove the '3;' and change your session.save_path to simply '/var/lib/php/sessions' for testing purposes? Also, which phpMyAdmin version is it?

Comment: You've installed your own phpMyAdmin via git but dpkg also reports the packaged phpMyAdmin is present. The challenge when loading the setup page comes from the packaged version, for instance; this is not built in to phpMyAdmin itself. Try removing one or the other, clearing your browser cache and any cookies starting with `pma` then try to load the page again.